# Massive data wrangling issue with election data. Grouped rows to columns?

Tags: r, group-by, transpose

I have downloaded data from the Oklahoma State Election Board related to the recent elections and am looking to transform this data in such a way that will allow for more sensible analysis. Unfortunately, the format the data has come in does not make this easy.

Currently, the data looks like this:

```
   precinct race_description cand_party cand_tot_votes
1     10001         GOVERNOR        DEM            106
2     10001         GOVERNOR        IND              5
3     10001         GOVERNOR        LIB              7
4     10001         GOVERNOR        REP            118
5     10002         GOVERNOR        DEM             84
6     10002         GOVERNOR        IND              9
7     10002         GOVERNOR        LIB              3
8     10002         GOVERNOR        REP            151
9     10003         GOVERNOR        DEM             36
10    10003         GOVERNOR        IND              2
```

Is there a way for me to collapse this down so that each precinct is just one row and the other data would be in a column? So I would have one row with precinct 10001 results, and a column header with something like "Gov Dem", "Gov Rep", and so on for each race?

I am not sure what to do to handle this problem to be quite honest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `names_sep` argument in `pivot_wider` to combine two of columns together for the names.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = c(race_description, cand_party),
    names_sep = "_",
    values_from = cand_tot_votes
  )
```

**Output**

```
  precinct GOVERNOR_DEM GOVERNOR_IND GOVERNOR_LIB GOVERNOR_REP
     <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>
1    10001          106            5            7          118
2    10002           84            9            3          151
3    10003           36            2           NA           NA
```

If you want different headings, then you can always clean those up prior to pivoting:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(race_description = str_extract(str_to_title(race_description), "^.{3}"),
         cand_party = str_to_title(cand_party)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = c(race_description, cand_party),
    names_sep = "_",
    values_from = cand_tot_votes
  )

#  precinct Gov_Dem Gov_Ind Gov_Lib Gov_Rep
#     <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
#1    10001     106       5       7     118
#2    10002      84       9       3     151
#3    10003      36       2      NA      NA
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(precinct = c(10001L, 10001L, 10001L, 10001L, 10002L, 
10002L, 10002L, 10002L, 10003L, 10003L), race_description = c("GOVERNOR", 
"GOVERNOR", "GOVERNOR", "GOVERNOR", "GOVERNOR", "GOVERNOR", "GOVERNOR", 
"GOVERNOR", "GOVERNOR", "GOVERNOR"), cand_party = c("DEM", "IND", 
"LIB", "REP", "DEM", "IND", "LIB", "REP", "DEM", "IND"), cand_tot_votes = c(106L, 
5L, 7L, 118L, 84L, 9L, 3L, 151L, 36L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```